# Running an Eclipse Created JBPM Project in JBPM Console

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jbpm, bpmn

I'm using JBPM 6.0.1 and attempting to run the sample-->evaluation project in the jbpm-console.

The program runs fine in Eclipse, and has been pushed to a repository in jbpm-installer system.  It shows in the JBPM Console's Explorer.  However, none of the Java or process files(*.bpmn) files or items show.

Could someone please explain and/or point me to the right place in the documentation that will explain:

1.) How an Eclipse created project needs to be structured so it will be recognized by the console when accessed from the repository

2.) How a Java application can be run from the console.

Thanks.

TU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

projects inside the jbpm console ng are maven projects, which means that they need to follow the maven conventions + have the kmodule.xml file. That should make it work for you. 
If you have a process in your project and you build it inside the console it will display the process definition inside the process definition screens.

Comment: Thanks!  As for running a Java program and integrating it with the console, where could I find some good examples?  I'm talking about something like downloading a PDF, verifying download success, and then performing various document checks.  So far I've only seen processes defined and no Java applications accompany them.